# Why is the internet not reachable on virtualbox VM but ok when VPN is off on the Windows host?

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtualbox, vpn

I have Windows 10 host and Ubuntu 16.04 guest vm on Virtualbox 6.0.18. I have Viscosity VPN client (1.8.5.1) on the Windows host, sending all traffic via VPN. The guest vm is set to NAT network type.

Until recently, I was able to connect to the internet from the guest vm even with VPN enabled on the host. However, something has changed and I can no longer connect to internet on the guest VM with VPN enabled on host. If VPN is off, I can connect.

Any suggestions on where I should look?

Comment: The first thing I would do here is to uninstall the VPN client, restart the host and guest and see if guest Internet returns. What is the result here?

Answer (score 3):

There have been a couple of changes in Viscosity 1.8.5.1 which appear to affect traffic from guests vms (Virtualbox) been routed through the VPN.

Thank you to Viscosity Support for clarifying.

The first major change is Viscosity's DNS Proxy changed from using 127.0.0.1/::1 to using 127.56.49.53/fd53:7061:726b:4c61:6273:5669:7344:4e53.

The second major change is Viscosity's DNS Proxy used to listen on each adapter, instead if now only listens on these two new IP addresses, port 53 in both cases.

It seems VirtualBox is using it's own DNS Proxy, though I'm not sure to what end, what it's designed to do, or why the changes in 1.8.5 would cause it to stop working if it was working in Viscosity 1.8.4.

It looks like there's an easy fix though, you can switch Virtualbox to use the host resolver instead of it's own proxy with the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" modifyvm "VM Name" --natdnshostresolver1 on
```

The following articles provide details.

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html
https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/vboxmanage-modifyvm.html